# Running XAMPP with Mysql instance already installed on local machine

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, xampp, mysql-workbench

I installed XAMPP on my local machine. I had previously installed MySQL along with Mysql Workbench. Couple of questions:

1. Do I have to start the MySQL services in Xampp?
2. what is my localhost IP address for connection in PHP?

I am running Windows 7. I am new with this and I am trying to use CakePHP and Xampp for a project and I am not sure how the previous installation of Mysql may conflict with Xampp.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Workbench is just a client that allows you to interface with MySQL database(s).

If you installed a Mysql server on your local machine when you installed Mysql workbench then you would already have a localhost on your machine before you installed XAMPP.

Yes, You would still have to start the Mysql services in XAMPP.

I had a similar situation when I installed a WAMP server on my local machine.  I uninstalled the Mysql server that I installed when I installed Mysql workbench (WAMP actually placed localhost data in its data directory, so I did not even have to move the data from Mysql server data directory, not sure if XAMPP does the same but you can easily check).  After uninstalling the Mysql server, the WAMP server was able to start its Mysql service..effectively taking over localhost.

By default your localhost is always at HOME (127.0.0.1)

Comment: Thank you BK and ramirio. I'm testing this for school and wasn't really sure how to go about it. I'll uninstall my existing mysql db and workbench.

Comment: Ah, from what I read I thought how you fixed it was by uninstalling the MySQL server. Thank you BK.

Comment: I do. I apologize as I meant the first instance of server that I installed together with workbench. Thanks again, you pointed me to the right direction. Cheers mate!

Comment: Will do mate. I am totally new here and would need 'reputation' before I can vote. Need to build it, hope I would. Thanks!